# retrieve id from a div inside a list of json objects in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I have searched for possible solutions online but did not find any solutions that actually work.I have tried multiple approaches but sadly none of them work according to the way that I need it work in this specific regard. I saw that I could use the href and button approach using the router but this is sadly not the specific solution required in this instance.

Basically I need to get the id value of a specific object displayed in a html list when a button is clicked on the browser. Say a list displays 2 json objects in html then when button 2 in the list is clicked I want to retrieve the id of that second element in the list to display later in another list or save it later in a database or whatever is clever.

The code of the list and array of objects is added here but code so far of how I tried to solve this is not listed because none of my attempts even worked and each attempt failed dismally(a bit over reacting but hey) :=(

So basically I need help and advice :=)

```
var details = [

    {
        id: 0,
        department: "HR",
        name: "samy",
        
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        department: "Accounting",
        name: "william",
        
    }


];
```

```
function displaydetails(parent, array) {
    var html = "";

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        //Set Our Itemp template
        let itemTemplate = `
  <li>
     <h2>${array[i].department}</h2>
     <div>name:  ${array[i].name}</div>
     <div>id:     ${array[i].id}</div>
     <div>  <button   id='retrieve-ID'  > GET ID </button>  </div>
     
  

  </li>`;
        //update the html 
        html += itemTemplate
    }
    //Update the parent once
    parent.innerHTML += html;
}

displaydetails(document.getElementById("detailslist"), details);
```

Comment: Never create duplicated IDs like `retrieve-ID`. IDs *must* be unique.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  could you elaborate as to why IDs should never be duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add an `onclick` handler to each button, which calls global function, passing the element, and then get the id:

```
  <div>  <button   id="${array[i].id}" onclick="getId(event, this)" > GET ID </button>  </div>
```

handler:

```
function getId(event, element) {
 
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('id: ', element.id);
}
```

Or you can just pass id as an argument, if you don't need the element:

```
onclick="getId(event, '${array[i].id}')"
```

Then you can use that id to search elements in the array by that id.

```
  const arrEl = details.find(el=>el.id == element.id);
```

```js
function getId(event, element) {
 
    event.preventDefault();
 
  const arrEl = details.find(el=>el.id == element.id);
  
  console.log('id: ', element.id, '\narray element:', arrEl);  
}


var details = [

    {
        id: 0,
        department: "HR",
        name: "samy",
        
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        department: "Accounting",
        name: "william",
        
    }


];

function displaydetails(parent, array) {
    var html = "";

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        //Set Our Itemp template
        let itemTemplate = `
  <li>
     <h2>${array[i].department}</h2>
     <div>name:  ${array[i].name}</div>
     <div>id:     ${array[i].id}</div>
     <div>  <button   id="${array[i].id}" onclick="getId(event, this)" > GET ID </button>  </div>
     
  

  </li>`;
        //update the html 
        html += itemTemplate
    }
    //Update the parent once
    parent.innerHTML += html;
}

displaydetails(document.getElementById("detailslist"), details);
```

```html
<ol id="detailslist"></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning clicks to each `<button>`, assign only one click listener to the parent and use **Event delegation** (which is also super useful if you add LI elements dynamically at a later time).
Store the user ID in the button's `data-*` attribute like = `data-userid="${user.id}"` and retrieve it in JS using `Element.dataset.userid`. Once you have the ID, use Array.prototype.find to search for that Object in your users (`details`) Array

```js
// DOM utils:
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Utils:
const getItem = (arr, key, val) => arr.find(item => item[key] === val);

// Task: Users: 
const displayDetails = (elWrapper, users) => {
  const elsList = users.map((user) => elNew("LI", {
    innerHTML: `<h2>${user.department}</h2>
      <div>Name: ${user.name}</div><div>id: ${user.id}</div>
      <button data-userid="${user.id}" type="button">GET ID</button>`
  }));
  elWrapper.append(...elsList);
};

const elParent = el("#detailslist");
const details = [
  { id: 0, department: "HR", name: "samy" },
  { id: 1, department: "Accounting", name: "william" },
  { id: 9, department: "Development", name: "S.O." },
];

// Events (delegated):
elParent.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.target.closest("[data-userid]");
  if (!elBtn) return; // Do nothing, not our button.
  
  const user = getItem(details, "id", +elBtn.dataset.userid);
  if (user) { // If user is found...
    console.log(user); // send user to server
  }
});

// Init:
displayDetails(elParent, details);
```

```html
<ul id="detailslist"></ul>
```